# is this an orthogonal matrix?

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

$T$ is a $4\times 4$ real matrix, and obeys $$T^\dagger \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & a & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & a^2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & a^2
\end{array}
\right) T = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & a & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & a^2 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & a^2
\end{array}
\right) $$ is $T$ an orthogonal matrix? If not, what ore do I need to ensure $T$ is orthogonal?

Other properties of $T$; $T^N=\mathbb{I}$ so $\det T=\pm 1$, $\alpha>1$.

Comment: Is that a matrix multiplication or a definition of $T$ and $T^\dagger$?

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether this equality is supposed to hold for every $a$ or for *some* $a$. I'm assuming the former, in which case @Algebraic Pavel's answer is perfect.

Comment: In addition to the previous comment, it is not actually clear what do you mean by "ensuring that $T$ is orthogonal". For what $a$ must the equation hold? Some additional constraints on $T$?

Comment: OK but does $T^\dagger AT=A$ hold for *all* positive $a$ or for a given *fixed* positive $a$?

Comment: for a fixed $\alpha$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The matrix $T$ does not need to be orthogonal unless $a=1$. Something else can be though if $a>0$. You can write $T^\dagger A T=A$. If $A$ is positive definite (if $a>0$), it has a unique positive definite square root $A^{1/2}$ (in this case, a diagonal matrix with square roots of the corresponding diagonal entries on the diagonal). Multiplying by $A^{-1/2}$ from left and right then gives 
$$I=(A^{-1/2}T^\dagger A^{1/2})(A^{1/2}TA^{-1/2})=(A^{1/2}TA^{-1/2})^\dagger(A^{1/2}TA^{-1/2}),$$ which means that $\tilde T:=A^{1/2}TA^{-1/2}$ is orthogonal.

---

**On the question "when is $T$ orthogonal":**

Partition $T$ as
$$
T=\pmatrix{P&Q\\R&S},
$$
where the four blocks are square matrices ($2\times 2$). Then $T^\dagger AT=A$ gives (assuming $\alpha\neq 0$)
$$
P^\dagger P+\alpha R^\dagger R=I, \quad Q^\dagger Q+\alpha S^\dagger S=\alpha I, \quad
P^\dagger Q+\alpha R^\dagger S=0.
$$
Note that $T^\dagger T$ is equivalent to
$$
P^\dagger P+R^\dagger R=I, \quad Q^\dagger Q+S^\dagger S= I, \quad
P^\dagger Q+R^\dagger S=0.
$$
We want both to be true. Looking on the first two equations from both sets, we get
$$
(\alpha-1)R^\dagger R=0, \quad (\alpha-1)Q^\dagger Q=0.
$$
So either $\alpha=1$ or $R$ and $Q$ are zero matrices (or both).

The case $\alpha=1$ is probably uninteresting, so let $\alpha\neq 1$ (and nonzero). Hence $R=Q=0$. The conditions above give that
$$
P^\dagger P=I, \quad S^\dagger S=I.
$$
So $T$ is block diagonal with orthogonal diagonal blocks.

On the other hand, if $T^\dagger A T=A$ holds for some $a\not\in\{0,1\}$ and $T$ is not block diagonal with orthogonal diagonal blocks, then $T$ is *not* orthogonal.

Comment: thanks! so can I use this to get any information about $T$? i.e. because $A^{1/2}$ and $A^{-1/2}$ are orthogonal and $A^{1/2}TA^{-1/2}$ is orthogonal does this imply $T$ is orthogonal in some case?

Comment: ah yes - because the product of two orthogonal matrices is also orthogonal, $A^{-1/2}\tilde{T}A^{1/2}$ is orthogonal therefore $T$ is orthogonal... right?

Comment: @jdizzle It depends what do you call "orthogonal matrix". For me, a square $X$ is orthogonal if $X^\dagger X=I$. With this definition, $A$ is not orthogonal unless $a=\pm 1$.

Comment: ah I see, so theres unless $\alpha = \pm 1$ then there is no way of telling if $T$ is orthogonal

Comment: @jdizzle Yes, that is necessary, otherwise the equality cannot hold if $a\neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks! this is amazingly helpful to me